# Change droplist options onSelectionChange in Axure

Tags: wireframe, axure

I'm trying to do a droplist chain in Axure RP 7 such as:

1. Select value in select #1
2. Change the values in select #2
3. Select value in select #2
4. Change the values in select #3
5. and so on

I tried searching how to accomplish this but it's not documented. I fear you cannot change options of a droplist in Axure RP 7 once it's been generated.

Can anyone confirm this or tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you cannot change the content of a droplist.

However, you can change a dynamic panel state depending on the option selected in a selectbox. This way, you may create something like this:

Selectbox #1
 DynamicPanel #1 (
  Selectbox #2
  DynamicPanel #2 (
  Selectbox #3
 )
)

Hope this helps.